# GCP quota and billing at user level

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

I am trying to see if there is a way for me to bill and restrict users based on their usage of resources across projects on our GCP instance.  I know billing and quotas officially are at the project level, but we will have shared projects which will be used by people in seperate cost codes.  I was thinking of building an API per cost code, and having people access the resources only through there, but I'm not sure if this is the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a grouping system where you use labels to track your [resources](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/10/using-labels-to-organize-Google-Cloud-Platform-resources.html). Using labels such as cost center, service and environment will allow you to track your GCP [resource usage and spending](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/12/use-labels-to-gain-visibility-into-GCP-resource-usage-and-spending.html).

Then you can export your billing data to BigQuery where it can be filtered and segmented by [labels](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery).

In terms of notifications and restricting access, you may set up budget alerts by following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets). Together with Cloud Pub/Sub budget notifications and Cloud Functions, you can have more control on your spending by capping costs and [stopping your billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify).

Comment: thanks but this doesn't help to identify the end users of resources, it seems its not something google can do right now.  All the stuff you say above applies to billing which is currently only at the project level.

Comment: In that case, please place a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) with how you want it to be implemented.